# Type Casting of values in scientific format(eg:1.565656E+02) in Import-Csv cmdlet

Tags: csv, powershell

I am still a beginner in Powershell. I am reading a tab delimited text file generated from a software to filter out a set of values. But the values generated are all in a format similar to IEEE floating point format. (*for example : 1.5656565656E+02*).

I tried the `'-as'` operator but of no use. I get an error. Please help me out to solve this or is there a possibility to do this.

My tab delimited file is something like this

```
Time [s]       Offset_Angle              observability_Analysis
0.00E+00      0.89040261167028E+00        0.00000000000000E+00
4.32E+02      0.21319658757004E+00        0.00000000000000E+00
8.64E+02      0.26803683992125E+00        0.00000000000000E+00
1.30E+03      2.67379011780784E+02        1.00000000000000E+00
1.73E+03      2.89704767087971E+02        1.00000000000000E+00
2.16E+03      2.93302157473406E+02        1.00000000000000E+00
```

The code i am working on is as below

```
$ap = Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Path E:\textreplace.txt

$abc = $ap|where-Object {$_.observability_Analysis -eq "1.00000000000000E+00”}|select-object –property Offset_Angle | Foreach-Object {$_.Offset_Angle = $_.Offset_Angle -as [float] $_ }
$abc|export-csv "E:\results.txt"
```

I am trying to filter those Offset_Angle values that have their observability_Analysis as 1.0000000000000E+00

For the second line it throws errors telling that

```
cannot convert the {Offset_Angle = 2.67379011780784E+02} value of type Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObjectstring.object to [float].
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: your command should work with a small modification....just add a semicolon like so `$_.Offset_Angle -as [float] ; $_`

Comment: @Kiran  Thanks .. It worked. But sorry for this silly mistake

Comment: great...no need to be sorry mistakes happen :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either expand the `Offset_Angle` property in the `Select`, or target it explicitly in the `ForEach` and then cast to `float` buy use of `[float]$variable`

Either of the below will work:

```
$ap | ? { $_.observability_Analysis -eq "1.00000000000000E+00" } | select -expand Offset_Angle | % { [float]$_ }

$ap | ? { $_.observability_Analysis -eq "1.00000000000000E+00" } | % { [float]$_.Offset_Angle }
```